# using two controllers to display different content in one view page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, linq, knockout.js

I have two controllers - one controller is to call the method to get job positions based on id passed in from url and the other controller is to call the method that will fill the job positions with the appropriate people.

first Controller will return to the view this:

Teachers
Assistants
Students

Second Controller will return to the view this:

Susan Smith
Jack John
Amanda
Bill
Casey
Zack

Both Controllers will return this to the view(final view)

Teachers
Susan Smith

Assistants
Jack John

Students
Amanda
Bill
Casey
Zack

Do i need to create a partial view or is there a way in which i could bind in both information into one view. I am using javascript and knockout with linq to render and show the information via data-binding. But i wanted to get a better understanding of the concept of how i should achieve this properly? I wasn't sure what parts of the code would be wanted but feel free to let me know.

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to implement? Do you need to show a list of teachers, students, assistants in same page?

Comment: @Murali yes the last view example i have displayed is what i want to show - i have a different call method that gets the positions and a method that gets the users that will fill the positions and all will be displayed in one page

Comment: Why would you not just serve the data up already bound together properly with a view model?

Comment: @PWKad in what way do you mean? I would like to mind the information in the knockout javascript and just doing a data-bind in the view

Comment: My thought is that you are probably relatively new to MVC, which could be an incorrect assumption, and have used the auto-scaffolding feature to create two controllers and are now trying to tie that information into a view.  A better solution is to create a view model (a model of your data intended for your view) and pass the data structure that way.